# JavaScript Video is not playing on Ipad and Android

Tags: javascript, android, video.js, video-player

I have some of Videos which are playing on Ipad / Android devices successfully but one Video is not playing on Ipad or Android while all Videos are working fine on Browser.

Video (which is not playing on ipad or Android) link is available [here](https://mega.nz/#!LVwSWZjJ!JPKT9Lfr4oi8YJK-wHd04Ji0n66Dz9kamn3qF0r8GzQ).

Is something with video or support to Ipad / Android?

What I tried I simply edited video JavaScript HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

  <!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
  <script src="video.js"></script>

  <!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
       <source src="Video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
    </video>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Error which comes:  The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried? Where did you fail? How does the stack trace look? I will not click your link.

Comment: I have edited my post with Code. I simply change source of video here.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the video to a lower h264 profile and level, e.g. with ffmpeg. Older devices are unable to play h.264 videos using the high profile, hence "the video used features your browser did not support". The baseline profile is most compatible.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this process, I created a mp4 video with ffmpeg but still I faced same error.